# How to debug timeouts when connecting a second ssh session on same server

Tags: linux, ssh, timeout

I'm experiencing intermittent problems opening multiple ssh sessions to the same server.

I'm using Affa 3, an rsync-over-ssh backup script for CentOS that connects using key pairs. I have several backup jobs on the same server that sometimes overlap.

I can open a connection, then when I try to open a second connection I get a timeout. Here's a bit of the log: (note that the port 222 is NATed to 22 on the server)

```
Tue Sep 29 01:34:14[18533]: Checking SSH connection to root@xx.xx.xx.xx
Tue Sep 29 01:34:14[18533]: Exec Cmd: /usr/bin/ssh -o ConnectTimeout=120 -o PasswordAuthentication=no -p 222 -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o HostKeyAlias=server1 -o UserKnownHostsFile=/root/.ssh/knownhosts-server1 root@xx.xx.xx.xx echo OK
Tue Sep 29 01:35:17[18533]: Exec Out: ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xx.xx port 222: Connection timed out
Tue Sep 29 01:35:17[18533]: Exec Out: exitstatus=255
```

If I `tail -f /var/log/secure`on the source server whilst the script runs, there is no trace of the login attempt. Am I looking in the right place?

If I have a previously established ssh session on the server (with PuTTY) the connection fails.

However, I can also have an open remote desktop session to a Windows server on the same distant network as the backup source server. This connection doesn't fail, and I can login using PuTTY from there!

I found an article refering to `/etc/security/limits.conf` but there is no limit to the number of connections configured there.

Does anyone have any ideas how to debug this problem?

Comment: Hmm, can you enable connection pooling so there is only one actual SSH connection? See `ControlMaster` in `ssh_config(5)`. (This also spares the cost of new connection creation.)

Comment: ControlMaster didn't help. Looks like it was a hardware/firmware problem. I changed the nic and everything seems to work.